# Lenovo thinkpad edge e550 laptop

Tags: laptop, display

Why does the screen brightness reduce when I plug in the charger?

Does it show that the battery needs a replacement?

Comment: check your power settings

Answer (score 0):

You can set different brightness levels for when your laptop is plugged in and when your laptop is not plugged in. You can search for power options in Control Panel and then check what power settings you are using.

This should be one of the main items on the power screen. Usually when your laptop is plugged in brightness will increase, but it is possible you switched them around by accident.